# cordova app close from my app

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

hi i am learning cordova i can manage to open an app from my app using **cordova plugin startapp** by using this code.

```
var sApp = startApp.set({
    "application":"com.application.name"
});
```

Start application with extra fields

```
var sApp = startApp.set({ /* params */
    "component": ["com.app.name","com.app.name.Activity"]
}, { /* extras */
    "extraKey1":"extraValue1",
    "extraKey2":"extraValue2"
});
```

but i am looking to close an app that is open using cordova.